# how to compare output of two ls in linux

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

So here is the task which I can't solve. I have a directory with .h files and a directory with .i files, which have the same names as the .h files. I want just by typing a command to have all .h files which are not found as .i files. It's not a hard problem, I can do it in some programming language, but I'm just curious how it will look like in cmd :). To be more specific here is the algo:

- get file names without extensions from ls *.h
- get file names without extensions from ls *.i
- compare them
- print all names from 1 that are not met in 2

Good luck!

Comment: Please have a look at sed program in linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
diff \
  <(ls dir.with.h | sed 's/\.h$//') \
  <(ls dir.with.i | sed 's/\.i$//') \
| grep '$<' \
| cut -c3-
```

`diff <(ls dir.with.h | sed 's/\.h$//') <(ls dir.with.i | sed 's/\.i$//')` executes `ls` on the two directories, cuts off the extensions, and compares the two lists. Then `grep '$<'` finds the files that are only in the first listing, and `cut -c3-` cuts off the `"< "` characters that `diff` inserted.

Comment: thanks for the super quick response. I tested and the results was :
ls: dir.with.i: No such file or directory
ls: dir.with.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I solved it by making little mod of your proposal:
comm -23   <(ls *.h | sed 's/\.h$//')   <(ls *.i | sed 's/\.i$//')
Thanks for the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
ls ./dir_h/*.h | sed -r -n  's:.*dir_h/([^.]*).h$:dir_i/\1.i:p' | xargs ls 2>&1 | \
grep "No such file or directory" | awk '{print $4}' | sed -n -r 's:dir_i/([^:]*).*:dir_h/\1:p'
```

Comment: The result from my test was :
such
such
such
But it should be :
hotfloorplan
hotspot
hotspot-iface
npe

such

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 dir1/*.hh dir2/*.ii | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' |awk -F"." '{a[$1]++;b[$0]}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]==1 && b[i".hh"]) print i}'
```

explanation:

```
ls -1 dir1/*.hh dir2/*.ii
```

above will list all the files *.hh and *.ii files in both the directories.

```
awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
```

above will just print the file name excluding the complete path of the file.

```
awk -F"." '{a[$1]++;b[$0]}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]==1 && b[i".hh"]) print i}'
```

above will create two  associative arrays one with file name and one with excluding the extension.
if both hh and ii files exist the value in the assosciative array will 2 if there is only one file then the value will be 1.so we need array item whose value is 1 and it should be a header file (.hh).
this can be checked using the asso..array b  which is done in the END  block.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working. Result was : ls: dir1/*.hh: No such file or directory
ls: dir2/*.ii: No such file or directory. Anyway it's a closed question. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bash is your shell:

```
for file in $( ls dir_with_h/*.h ); do
    name=${file%\.h};         # trim trailing ".h" file extension
    name=${name#dir_with_h/}; # trim leading folder name
    if [ ! -e dir_with_i/${name}.i ]; then
        echo ${name};
    fi
done
```

Undoubtedly this can be ported to virtually all other shells. I find this less cryptic than some other approaches (although this is surely my problem) but it is a *little* wordy. As such. a shell script might help recall it.